# The page "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" should include a link to "How not to be a spammer"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spam, help-center, self-promotion

The [help/behavior](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) page has a brief section **Avoid overt self-promotion**. I think it should include a link to the recently added [help/promotion](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) page with much more specific guidance.

This would be consistent with how the section **Be nice** of [help/behavior](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) links to the more detailed page [help/be-nice](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the `/help/behavior` page ("Expected Behavior") network-wide to add a link to the `/help/promotion` page ("How to not be a spammer").

[Here's the MSE version of the Expected Behavior page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) – I've added the following line between the last 2 paragraphs:

> For more detailed guidelines, see the Help Center page on [how to not be a spammer](/help/promotion).